# Problems with Nested Functions

Tags: python, function, nested

**THIS TURNED OUT TO BE A SYNTAX ERROR ON MY PART A LINE EARLIER IN THE CODE.**

Hello, I'm having some trouble with a nested function I wrote in python. Here is the relevant code.

```
device = "/dev/sr0"
def burn():  
  global device


  burnaudiotrack(device)
  createiso(device)  
  burntrack2(device)
```

I'm confused, because every time I try to run the script, python returns this:

```
    File "./install.py", line 72
    burnaudiotrack(device)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've nested functions before, and done so in a similar manner. I feel like I'm missing something fairly obvious here, but I can't pinpoint it. Thank you for your help/suggestions!.

EDIT:

Full code: (I tried to just post relevant info in the original)
http://dpaste.com/hold/291347/

It's a tad messy, and there may be other errors, but this one is vexing me at the moment.

Comment: Can you paste the entire file, possibly to dpaste or similar site?

Comment: this is valid python, no SyntaxError

Comment: What version of Python? The above code works for me (with stubs for the `burnaudiotrack`, `createiso` and `burntrack2` functions) on Python 2.5 and Python 2.6.

Comment: I'm using python 2.6.5 under a modern Linux Kernel (2.6.33). The full code is in the post. I also thought this syntax was fine, so I'm guessing there's something amiss elsewhere in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a close parenthesis on line 61.

Looks like the quote and paren at the end of the line are swapped.

```
speed = raw_input("Recomended(4);Default(8))"
```

should be

```
speed = raw_input("Recomended(4);Default(8)")
```

Comment: I want to hide away in shameful embarrassment now. Thanks for pointing that out, I probably would've wasted time re-writing sections of the code without purpose otherwise.

Comment: No worries; this is why posting the full source is good, get another set of eyes on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted into your question appears to have tabs as well as spaces. You should (according to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) always use *spaces* for indenting in Python. Check your text editor settings.

What's probably happened is you have some mix of tabs and spaces that *looks* correct in your editor, but is being interpreted differently by the Python compiler. The Python compiler sees a different inconsistent indenting, and throws a SyntaxError.

**Update**: As another answer points out, you are missing a closing parenthesis on a line of code you didn't show in your original question. Nevertheless, my comments about tabs in your source still hold.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but the actual code I'm running was all formatted by the same editor (With tabs). I already made sure that wasn't the issue before posting. Thanks for the suggestion though!